# remove method removes item from first list, but doesn't from the rest

Tags: java, list, dictionary, methods

I have this issue in my remove method that I don't quite understand.

When executing this method, it iterates through the first map (titleMap) and removes the title of the book item from that map, but will not go further on to execute the two other iterators.

A book item has a title, seller and price. There is a map for each attribute: titleMap, sellerMap, priceMap. I want to be able to remove the complete book item, so remove title of book from titleMap, seller from sellerMap and price from priceMap.

I've attempted to merge the three iterators together but to no avail. If anyone could help me find the reason for this that would be great. Thanks.

Input:

```
ListMultiIndex list = new ListMultiIndex();
    list.add("ONE", "Chris", 2);
    list.add("TWO", "Bob", 35);
    list.add("THREE","David", 100);
    list.displaySizeOfList();

    try {
        list.remove(new BookItem ("THREE","David", 100));
        list.remove(new BookItem ("TWO", "Bob", 35));
    } catch (BookStoreException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    list.displaySizeOfList();
```

Output:

The size of titleMap is: 3 
The size of sellerMap is: 3 
The size of priceMap is: 3 
book Removed (via titleMap)with title name: THREE 
book Removed (via titleMap)with title name: TWO 
The size of titleMap is: 1 
The size of sellerMap is: 3 
The size of priceMap is: 3

Output without error should look like:

The size of titleMap is: 1 
The size of sellerMap is: 1 
The size of priceMao is: 1

Method:

```
@Override
public void remove(IBookItem book) throws BookStoreException{

                boolean isRemoved = false;

    for(BookEntry<String,ArrayList<BookItem>> entry : titleMap){
        if(entry.getKey().equals(book.getTitle())){
            if(entry.getValue().contains(book)) {
                entry.getValue().remove(book);
                System.out.println("book Removed (via titleMap)with title name: " + book.getTitle());
                if(entry.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                    isRemoved = true;
                    System.out.println("book removed (titlemap)");
                    titleMap.remove(entry);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    isRemoved = false;
    for(BookEntry<String,ArrayList<BookItem>> entry2 : sellerMap){
        if(entry2.getKey().equals(book.getSeller())){
            if(entry2.getValue().contains(book)) {
                entry2.getValue().remove(book);
                System.out.println("entry.getValue,getremove");
                System.out.println("book Removed (via titleMap)with title name: " + book.getSeller());
                if(entry2.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                    isRemoved = true;
                    System.out.println("book removed (titlemap)");
                    sellerMap.remove(entry2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    isRemoved = false;
    for(BookEntry<Integer,ArrayList<BookItem>> entry3 : priceMap){
        if(entry3.getKey().equals(book.getSeller())){
            if(entry3.getValue().contains(book)) {
                entry3.getValue().remove(book);
                System.out.println("entry.getValue,getremove");
                System.out.println("book Removed (via titleMap)with title name: " + book.getSeller());
                if(entry3.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                    isRemoved = true;
                    System.out.println("book removed (titlemap)");
                    sellerMap.remove(entry3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I answered your other question but I didn't realize you wanted every loop to run.  Instead of using `return` just use `break`.  If there is a possibility that multiple item may match in your loops don't break at all and just let the loop finish naturally.  I would still advise you to return objects that were removed as a way to tell if the method worked.  Throwing an exception is really not the correct way.

I think your problem is also that you are iterating over an `iterator` and removing things from the backing collection.  Instead of this:

```
titleMap.remove(t);
```

You should use:

```
it.remove(t);
```

Removing items from a collection white iterating is a no no.

Another thing I would do is change your iterator loops.  Using a `while` loop is considerably more readable.  Example:

```
Iterator<BookEntry<String, ArrayList<BookItem>>> it = titleMap.iterator()
while (it.hasNext())
{
  /*if book doesn't exist*/
  it.remove();
}
```

Comment: I've attempted to replace return for break, and attempted removing return altogether, but neither seem to change the result of the method. Any ideas?

Comment: I would try debugging and stepping through the code to find out where it is prematurely exiting.

Comment: Just edited my answer for you, I think you had 2 problems.

Comment: I'll try out your advice and get back to you if I have found a solution or more problems. Thanks!

Comment: I've changed my method so that I'm using your version f the iterator and so it no longer removes from the collection, but like before, it's still not solving the issue, it still doesn't evaluate the other iterators

Comment: Just added the most recent version of the code. It's fairly similar but still has the same issue. I've checked other classes in case there was a problem but can't seem to find anything indicating an issue. The add method definitely works.

Comment: Just looked at the new code, a couple things. Don't reset isRemoved after every loop.  You've changed from using an iterator to just using a straight `for in`, you still can't remove items from a collection when doing this.  The only way you should remove items from a collection white iterating is using an `iterator`.  I'll edit my answer to include where the iterator remove should be.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your loops `return ;`

When this line is executed, the whole method ends and do not continue.